# CSV to php array separated by an empty line

Tags: php, csv

i am trying to pass a csv into a php array like this

```
Suleman Ayy
abc.com

Engr. cison
abxc@yahoo.com

Akin ABCD
abcd@gmail.com
```

so i can have an array in php..

this is my code, but it doesn't seem to work

```
$file = fopen($target_file, 'r');
$csvfile = fgetcsv($file);

$data = explode("\n", $csvfile);

foreach ($data as $line)
{
   $arr = explode("\t", $line);

// $arr[0] will have every first field of every row, $arr[1] the 2nd, ...
// Usually this is what I want when working with a csv file

// But if you rather want a multidimensional array, you can simply add 
// $arr to a different array and after this loop you are good to go.
}
```

Comment: the problem is that you are re-assigning the results to the same `$arr` variable for each loop `$arr = explode("\t", $line);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$csv = file_get_contents('yourfile.csv');

$newDelimiter = " ";
$arr = array();
foreach(preg_split('~\R\R~',$csv) as $line){
  $line = preg_replace('~\R~',$newDelimiter,$line);
  $arr[] = str_getcsv($line, $newDelimiter);
}

//test output
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Suleman"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "Ayy"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "abc.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Engr."
    [1]=>
    string(5) "cison"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "abxc@yahoo.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Akin"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "ABCD"
    [2]=>
    string(14) "abcd@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but i wanted all the names in one elemet

Comment: Then simply replace the space in the assignment for $newDelimiter with a character that does not appear in your texts (semicolon?)